# Where is the windows store located in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, arch-linux, wine, microsoft-store, steam-os

Im trying to move the windows store to a linux system to run it using wine. Is this even possible? If so, where is the windows store located, and what are other necesarry files i need to transfer? I have already copied over the 4 folders from WindowsApps/Microsoft.Windows.Store[long string here] but the WinStore.App.exe doesnt do anything, except give an error message (even on my Windows 10 PC, the microsoft store from the start menu works fine)
Now, can anyone help? Cheers! ^^

Comment: The Windows Store is located on the Microsoft cloud servers. Good luck in copying it.

Comment: WINE does not have the capability to run UWP applications.  Windows Store is a UWP application.

Comment: Perhaps in VBox: https://appuals.com/how-to-setup-windows-10-on-virtualbox/

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? No, not what you think you're trying to accomplish here, but taking some steps back: What were you trying to do when you came to the conclusion you needed to try running the Store in Linux? Were you trying to install and run some other app FROM the store? Then THAT is your question and what you should be trying for. I included links to others who have actually had some success doing that in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting Ramhound's comment as an answer, since it is the answer:

Windows Store app is a [Universal Windows Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) (UWP) application.

Some report some success running certain UWP applications in WINE:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111881/how-to-run-windows-store-apps-on-linux
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/991858/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-uwp-apps-on-ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103884/is-working-universal-windows-platform-uwp-on-linux-mac-based-on-dotnet-cor/43282554#43282554

But this is probably very dependent on HOW these apps utilize UWP. If they are otherwise self-contained WINE-compatible executables that are just packaged was UWP in order to be found in the Store, they may work, but there are aspects of UWP that are not supported in WINE.

The Windows Store app itself only really exists to download and install other apps and keep them updated, a function that WINE would be hard pressed to support.

Taking a few steps back and questioning your assumptions, I wonder if you're trying to use some other Windows Store app on your Linux computer, and it would be better to focus on THAT, rather than trying to get the entire store running in Linux.

Comment: I was trying to run Sea of Thieves on my steam deck, as i bought it on the Microsoft Store back then. I just think it maybe needs some kind of connection to the store / the xbox app (which is connected to the store)

Comment: That information needs to be your question then. The Store won't run in Wine. We don't know if SoT will, but there's a better chance it might, but... I wouldn't bet on it, especially given it's strong dependence on networking for its required online functions.